# Enabling Personal Hotspot feature

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, tethering

My current carrier does not allow the Personal Hotspot feature for iPhone 4 so this option is missing in the menu. Is there a way I can enable this? I don't mind jailbreaking it. I don't want to use MiWi or any aditional application. I want to use the native one. Thanks

Comment: Which carrier would that be?

Comment: Movistar in Peru

Comment: Ooh. A non-standard carrier...

Comment: What iOS version are you on ?

Comment: I'm on iOS 5.1, the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable tethering (aka Personal Hotspot) you need to load a modified "carrier file", to do that you'll need what's known as the "Wortel Commcenter Patch."

1. Jailbreak
2. Install the Commcenter Patch through Cydia from [this repo](http://v.backspace.jp/repo/)
3. Reboot
4. Edit your carrier.plist according to [these instructions](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=984943) :

> 1. browse to /System/Library/Carrier Bundes/your_carrier.bundle/
> 2. Download your carrier.plist file from your iPhone and save a copy of this original file, just in case.
> 3. Open the downloaded carrier.plist in your favorite text editor
> 4. Under APNS->APN look for something with your carriers WAP settings. Change the type mask integer from 4 to 53 - which should
>      change allowing MMS to MMS, data and tethering. A explanation of these
>      numbers is here. If this does not work, play around with the numbers
>      until something works for your specific carrier.
> 5. save the file to a different location and replace the file on your phone.
> 6. On your iPhone, open Settings / General / Reset and reset your network settings.

References:

[CommCenter patch for iOS5](http://www.hackint0sh.org/general-127/commcenter-patch-ios5-327203-4.htm)

[Tethering on jail broken ios5](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1303617)

I've not personally done this since iOS 4.2. It's a dark art and caution is advised.

Answer (score 2):

[Tetherme](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=tethermeData) is an app you can purchase and install on a jailbroken device that will attempt to enable the iOS personal hotspot feature on devices and with carriers that don't support it.

Reports are mixed, some user indicating it doesn't work with their particular configuration, others reporting that some carriers detect this usage and disconnect when the personal hotspot is active.

While you are interested in using the iOS personal hotspot, chances are good that the more reliable method is to use a third party utility.

However, if you must use the iOS personal hotspot feature, tetherme seems to be only available option right now.

Comment: If possible, can you add a link please?

Comment: @daviesgeek Done.